# flashing content of *ngIf using an Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-ng-if

I develop an Angular app.
I want to display some text when my app is not in production, otherwise nothing.
I have the following code, where environment is an observable:

```
<span *ngIf="(environment | async) !== 'production'">bla bla text...
```

The problem is that it shows the content as long as the observable is not resolved.

I think this resolves to :

```
undefined !== 'somestring'
```

and therefore the condition is validated and the text displayed. This is not what I want, I want no display, no evaluation of the expression before resolution of the observable.

What syntax should I use to prevent the flash of undesired content ?

thanks for any help

Comment: For reference: https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-ngif-async-pipe

Comment: Curious, does this do it? `<span *ngIf="(environment | async)? !== 'production'">bla bla text...`

Comment: @Adam I would have loved it but : Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token !== at column 24 in [(environment | async)? !== 'production']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test for the `undefined`, `null` and `'production'` with `Array.indexOf`:

```
<span *ngIf="[undefined, null, 'production'].indexOf(environment | async) < 0">
```

Comment: unfortunately I do not know the list of possible environments. No white list, only a blacklist

Comment: OK. I modified my answer.

Comment: this looked good, but I still have the flash. Before resolution, is environment undefined, or is it an observable object ?

Comment: Try adding `null` to the list (I also changed `'prod'` for `'production'` in my example).

Comment: null works in this case. thanks !. Now I need to get it working with : [ngClass]="{'nonproduction': ([null, 'devel'].indexOf(environment | async) < 0) }">

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `[ngClass]="{'nonproduction': [null, 'production'].indexOf(environment | async) < 0) }"`.

Comment: Are you sure ? there is two closing parenthesis in your code, only one opening

Comment: Yeah. You can remove the last closing parenthesis. :-)

Comment: ah ok, I had 'devel' in there just for testing purpose without changing the backend. sorry for confusing you with this typo.

Comment: Solved it : [ngClass]="{'nonproduction': ([null, 'devel'].indexOf($any(environment) | async) < 0)}

Answer (score 5):

Subscribe once and for all in your component, and test the actual emitted value in your template:

```
<span *ngIf="env && env !== 'production'">
```

Or subscribe once in your template, and store the result in a variable:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="environment | async as env">
  <span *ngIf="env !== 'production'">
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Not using observable in template is indeed a solution, but wanted a way to use them in there. Your second proposal is a bit verbose imo, and not convenient to generalize.

Comment: It is the recommended way to use async: you subscribe once, and only once, and assign the result to a variable that you can use as many times as you want without resubscribing again and again. Remember that every time you use async in a template, you subscribe to the observable. If it's cold, you thus trigger the pipeline again. If it's an HTTP observable, you send a new HTTP request every time.

Comment: So it is not good to use observables directly in a template ? Then the async pipe is a little bit  misleading toward the wrong pattern (we had that kind of cases already in angularjs)

Comment: It is absolutely fine, but you must understand how it works, what it implies, and how best to write your code to avoid nasty situations.

Comment: Sure, this is true for everything. Until now I thought that async pipe was totally harmless, and that it was better to shrink the component size and push stuff into the template. I ll know better now